# Can I use a variable with .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an interactive textarea where a user can enter HTML and the resulting display will be shown in a box below. Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>
function readout(){
    var getCode = document.getElementById("tryit").value;
    document.getElementById("readout").innerHTML = getCode;
};
</script>
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<textarea name="tryit" id="tryit"></textarea>

<p>Then click submit</p>

<button type="button" onclick="readout()">Submit</button>

<p id="readout" style="height:100px; width:300px; border:1px solid black;"></p>
```

Comment: I just forgot to put that code in. I have it.

Comment: What is your question? Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/xcsq1w8y/1/

Comment: Yes, you can use variable. What's the problem you are facing?? With this code?

Comment: Yes, I know it _should_ work, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, open your JS console (F12) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: I checked the console and it said by `onclick="readout()"`that `readout()` is not a function. Is it just not running the Javascript?

Comment: I tried putting the code in my `<head>` instead of at the end of the body. It worked then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @blex mentioned, innerHTML can indeed display variable content.

```js
function readout(){
    var getCode = document.getElementById("tryit").value;
    document.getElementById("readout").innerHTML = getCode;
};

readout();
```

```html
<textarea name="tryit" id="tryit">
<h1>Hi</h1>
</textarea>

<p>Then click submit</p>

<button type="button" onclick="readout()">Submit</button>

<p id="readout" style="height:100px; width:300px; border:1px solid black;"></p>
```